# Font Awesome Icons, how can i add a grow hover effect?

Tags: html, css, hover, font-awesome

I'm making a website and im trying to add some Font Awesome Icons that grow on hover.

This is what i have so far using this code:

https://gyazo.com/a3c87288fe3b02439b577e585a73894d

```
<ul>
  <a href="https://instagram.com">
  <em class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x" style="color:white">&nbsp;</em>
  </a>
</ul
```

Now i would like to add add a slight grow effect when you hover over them.

Thanks in advance, as you can problly tell i'm new to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
.fa { 
  transition:.5s; /* this is grow duration */
}

.fa:hover {
transform:scale(1.5); /* this is grow amount */
}
```

Comment: Did everything you said, works like a charm, i'm forever grateful sir!